# Flutter local notification causing crash, only in the APK version

Tags: android, flutter

I had this app working before the 1.9 update, then a failure to build had to be worked around by switching the gradle version from 3.2.1 to 3.3.1

Ever since, any non-configuration calls to the local notification pluggin are met with this stacktrace:

```
E/flutter (22738): [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(39)] java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: Drawable
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.b.a.ja$a.<init>(:12)
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.b.a.V.a(:5)
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.p.a(:18)
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.b.a.p.a(:21)
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.b.a.p.a(:37)
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.b.a.p.a(:17)
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.p.a(:18)
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.b.a.c.a(:5)
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.p.a(:18)
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.p.a(:96)
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.p.a(:86)
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.p.a(:84)
E/flutter (22738):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.d.e(:7)
E/flutter (22738):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.d.a(:49)
E/flutter (22738):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.d.a(:157)
E/flutter (22738):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.d.b(:40)
E/flutter (22738):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.d.a(:132)
E/flutter (22738):      at d.a.b.a.m$a.a(:2)
E/flutter (22738):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.c.a(:14)
E/flutter (22738):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(:2)
E/flutter (22738):      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (22738):      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/flutter (22738):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
E/flutter (22738):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
E/flutter (22738):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (22738):      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/flutter (22738):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/flutter (22738): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: Drawable
E/flutter (22738):      at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1601)
E/flutter (22738):      at c.a.a.b.a.ja$a.<init>(:6)
E/flutter (22738):      ... 26 more
E/flutter (22738): 
F/flutter (22738): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(76)] Check failed: CheckException(env).
```

I made no changes to the code from the version that was working.
The code used to configure the plugin is ran on init as follows

```dart
  void inicializarPluginNotificacoes() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/app_icon24');
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(initializationSettingsAndroid, null);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings, onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }
```

and the call to the plugin is made like this:

```dart
  Future marcarNotificacao(int id, int hora, int minuto, String texto, String titulo) async {
    var scheduledNotificationDateTime = new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(hours: hora, minutes: minuto));
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails('ponto_unb', 'Ponto', 'Notificações para o ponto eletrônico');
    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, null);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(id); // crashes
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(id, titulo, texto, scheduledNotificationDateTime, platformChannelSpecifics); // also crashes if the other one is not called first
  }
```

Now, the intresting thing is, the crash only takes place after installing the apk. On a development build with flutter run or a debug run the crash doesn't happen.

Things i've tried:
- Checking the icon since the message mentions drawable. The configuration doesn't even run if the icon is not found.

- Catching the exception with a try/catch around the call: the exception goes right through
- Checking notification permissions, its all fine, as i mentioned, the code was working prior to the update
- The calls are made with corect times ( hours and minutes ), and even if they weren't the cancel call still would crash the app
- Check if the cancel call to an id without scheduled notifications would crash, it didn't on the version that worked prior to the update
- adding importance, priority and changing the channel name and id, didn't work, was getting desperate at this point

I feel like there is some resource i'm missing, is there a way to obtain a more comprehensive look into the crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the exact same issue.

I used the following:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
           minifyEnabled false
}
    }
```

Please note that this disables your proguard.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Thanks for the warm welcome :).

From what I know -> "AAPT2 generates keep rules based on references to classes in your app’s manifest, layouts, and other app resources. For example, AAPT2 includes a keep rule for each Activity that you register in your app’s manifest as an entry point."

So, this "Drawable" is getting "optimized", so I guess it's gone in a release build due to this, creating this issue.

Comment: was very hopefull, but still getting the same error, had to activate             shrinkResources false too to get the build to work

Comment: Disabling minification is not a good solution. You should add `-keep class com.dexterous.** { *; }` line to your proguard-rules file.

Answer (score 39):

I had the same problem and it was driving me nuts. It only happens on a release build and appears to be related to AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon')

The [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#android-integration) docs section on Android Integration says to add

```
-keep class com.dexterous.** { *; }
```

to /android/app/proguard-rules.pro

Comment: Worked for me. And apk size was drastically reduced.

Comment: Work for me too. I think was the resources of the app.

Comment: Worked for me! I think I spent ~3 days on and off trying to fix this crash in my release build. Lesson learned, read all of the docu. This should be the solution to this question.

Comment: Quick follow up, Flutter recommends using R8 now so no need for ProGuard anymore.
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#r8

Comment: Not sure why it is so complicated in Android, I am trying to figure this out for days...in my flutter app I couldnt find the proguard file...do I need to create one?

Comment: This also worked for me. I didn't have the proguard-rules.pro file so I created one. And everything worked perfectly. @Ned Couldn't agree more. Read Docs haha

Answer (score 5):

If you export release apk format so after installed crash the app.
You have to make these steps:

1. Added `proguard-files.pro` [file](https://github.com/iampawan/Flutter-UI-Kit/blob/master/android/app/proguard-rules.pro)
   Than you have to added bottom of the file this code

```
## flutter_local_notification plugin rules
-keep class com.dexterous.** { *; }
```

1. Your build.gradle file have to be

```
buildTypes {

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
        // your project's release build type.
        minifyEnabled false

        // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
        // Android Gradle plugin.
        shrinkResources false

        // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
        // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
        // R8 configuration files.
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same problem. I added the following line to the proguard-rules.pro `-keep class com.dexterous.** { *; }` but nothing worked. Problem was that proguard-rules.pro file was located in the local notifications plugin library.

So I created a copy of this file in `android/app` directory and finally it works. I have spent almost 2 days on this issue.

Do not forget to add the following code in `res/raw/keep.xml` file to keep your icon resource for your notification file [as shown here](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/src/main/res/raw/keep.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@drawable/*,@raw/slow_spring_board" />
```

Answer (score 3):

i try to add:

> -keep class com.dexterous.** { *; }

in proguard-rules.pro, but still got crash in APK version, and then i try to set false in

```
build.gradle
  buildTypes {
    release {
       minifyEnabled false
       shrinkResources false
       }
      }
```

and it works for me

Answer (score 2):

Setting `minifyEnabled false` will disable your proguard!

you can add this rule `-keepclassmembers enum * {*;}` to your /android/app/proguard-rules.pro to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and these 2 changes works for me: (I'm building an appbundle)

**1)**

If you build an App Bundle Edit **android/gradle.properties** and add the flag:

```
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
```

If you build an APK Make sure **android/app/src/AndroidManifest.xml** doesn’t set `android:extractNativeLibs=false` in the `<application>` tag.

**2)**

```
flutter build appbundle --no-shrink
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#r8

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you should do is:

1. Create a file called proguard-rules.pro
2. Copy [this](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/proguard-rules.pro) and paste in the created file (proguard-rules.pro).

```
-keep class com.dexterous.** { *; }
```

3. Build.

You can read more details about why to do this in the package documentation.

Comment: The "this" link is problematic; could you please [edit] the answer to include all the required code?